# Text input vs. Text Area

Tags: javascript, forms, input, textarea, mandrill

I'm using the Mandrill App for a contact form on a website. I understand that using "input type" works for me but not text area. How can I make text area work?

ex.
`<input type="text" class="inputMessage messageHeight required" name="message" id="thetext" placeholder="MESSAGE"/>`

This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nightcoregirl/owLsvqa4/1/

Comment: "*I understand that using "input type" works for me but not text area*" - how does using a `<textarea>` not work for you?

Comment: The email doesn't get sent if the message is sent via a text area instead of an input type field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your input text box with textarea like below:

```
        <textarea class="inputMessage messageHeight required" name="message" id="thetext" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
```

In your `submit` event handler, you're referring to the `id thetext` so that must be kept intact.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/Lnqdygc4/)**

Comment: for some reason the emails don't get sent with your method.

Comment: @Lil-Kim check this, I've printed the mandrill object as well http://jsbin.com/fedakomupa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Lil-Kim Did you try the jsbin?

Comment: My bad! It works mandrill app was justtaking a long time last night for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

The  tag defines a multi-line text input control.

A text area can hold an unlimited number of characters, and the text renders in a fixed-width font (usually Courier).

The size of a text area can be specified by the cols and rows attributes, or even better; through CSS' height and width properties.